# sencha touch: how to build an editable FormPanel

Tags: sencha-touch, formpanel

i want to build an editable FormPanel where a 'edit'-button in the toolbar makes the form editable and lets appear a 'cancel'- and a 'save'-button, changing the forms to be disabled:false.

has anyone a good example-page in the back of his mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see the sample on sencha website: 
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/forms/
I hope that helps.